# Cookies not set in Vercel but work locally

Tags: node.js, cookies, vercel

After deployment to Vercel cookies cannot be set in the function below:

```
const logIn = (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, cookieAge } = req.body;
  const throwError = (res) => res.status(500).send({ message: "The credentials are incorrect. Please try again." });
  let userFound;
  User
    .findOne({ email: email })
    .then(user => {
      userFound = user;
      return bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    })
    .then(passwordValidation => {
      if (passwordValidation) {
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: userFound.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        // console.log("token:", token);
        res.cookie("access-token", token, { maxAge: cookieAge, domain: ".vercel.app" });
        res.json(true);
      } else {
        throwError(res);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => throwError(res));
};
```

Here are the response headers:
[image]

So what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue as I was having the same problem. I switched the order of the response chain. Set the cooke first before the body response. See the cookie set in the response screenshot

```
  ...
  response.setHeader('Set-Cookie',['type=ninja']).status(200).json({
    body: res
  });
```

[image]